# Let A be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Then show that $A\cap B' \subseteq \overline{A\cap B} $.

Tags: real-analysis

Here, $B'$ denote the set of all accumulation points of $B$ and $\overline{A\cap B}$ denote the set of all adherent points of $A\cap B $.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{(A \cap B)}$ `\overline{(A \cap B)}`?